# RDLC Expression Extension Methods

Tags: reporting-services, expression, rdlc, ssrs-expression

Is it possible to write extension methods for expressions behind RDLC fields?

For example, let's say that I have a DateTime field in my datasource that may either have a valid value or may be null.  I drag and drop a TextBox onto my RDLC and format its value using the ToShortDateString() method.  This works fine for populated DateTime value, but this will also obviously throw an exception at runtime if I try to do a .ToShortDateString() on a NULL field.

I was wondering if I could write an extension method that I could use in my RDLC expressions so that when I'm dealing with ?DateTime values, I could call a method like .ConvertFromNullToEmptyString().

Of course there are other ways to work around this issue, but I was wondering if extension methods for use in RDLC expressions would be a possible approach to my business problem.

Thanks folks!

Comment: +1: Good question. I believe so but never had time to figure out. I hope someone answers!

Comment: I'm guessing this simply is not possible; too bad - I was looking forward to rewarding a bounty based on a conclusive answer here.

Comment: are you using ssrs, or the asp.net report viewer control. I ask because an RDL file is an ssrs report definition language file, while an RDLC is a report definition client language file, which is used by asp.net to display a report, sans ssrs

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You can either [embed code directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238.aspx#Embedded) in the report or include a [custom assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238.aspx#Custom).

Comment: Those aren't examples of using extension methods - which is what the question is asking...

Comment: @DanP: while this doesn't add extension methods, calling the code is the done in the same way as the normal expressions.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use extension methods, but not AS extension methods on an instance of an object. You would have to call them as a static method call on the type of which they are a member. So instead of `myDictionary.Values.Sum()` -- calling the `Sum` method on the `Values` property of a dictionary instance -- you could use `System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(myDictionary.Values)` -- passing the instance into the static `Sum` method of the `Enumerable` type (in this example, the report must reference the `System.Core` assembly). So yes, you can use methods that are also extensions, but (it appears anyway) not as extensions on a particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Corina on the solution to the question, I believe a better solution can be reached without going the route she suggests, using built in expressions. In any case where you have a DateTime coming from SQL, you're correct, it can be null, however, you can easily test for this using an `IIF` statement (remember that the expressions are basically in VB) to check for `null` / `nothing` / `empty` and as long as it is something, run the desired operation, otherwise return blank. Just be careful, as the resulting type of the `IIF` will probably be string.

Comment: While I can't spreak for the OP or AMissico; I'm personally interested in extension methods specifically. It is already very well known how to use arbitrary custom code in a report - so answers along those lines are somewhat pointless...

Comment: One of the challenges with what you're asking is that reflection is probably being used to execute the method, so if you call .ConvertFromNullToEmptyString() on the null object (null datetime), you'll get a null reference exception regardless, unless you rewrote the DateTime? object to have a static method called ConvertFromNullToEmptyString which would provide the functionality you're asking for. At the moment, I don't see how this particular piece of functionality benefits you more than a some custom code.

Comment: @CodeMonkey1313 I just post an answer covering that issue. It uses the `If()` ternary operator instead of the `IIf()` function.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, let's say that I have a DateTime field in my datasource that may either have a valid value or may be null. I drag and drop a TextBox onto my RDLC and format its value using the ToShortDateString() method. This works fine for populated DateTime value, but this will also obviously throw an exception at runtime if I try to do a .ToShortDateString() on a NULL field.

There should be no need for a custom function in your case. Just use VB's [`If()` ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator):

```vb
=If(Fields!MyDate.Value IsNot Nothing, Fields!MyDate.Value.ToShortDateString(), "N/A")
```

(Personally, I funnel my objects through AutoMapper and let it substitute `null` values with default values or objects, so that I don't have to deal with `null` values in the report at all).

---

It should be mentioned, that the `If(condition, true_part, false_part)` *ternary operator* should (with one `I`) be preferred over the `IIf(condition, true_part, false_part)` *function* (with two `I`'s) in most cases.

The `If()` ternary operator will short-circuit evaluate only the part that corresponds to condition outcome (e.g. a condition that is `True` will only evaluate the `true_part`).

The `IIf()` function will always evaluate the condition and both parts, because it is just a function call and all parameters of the function will be evaluated before the call.